# How to fix Key Error of variable not found in index? Python

Tags: python, matching, fuzzywuzzy, python-dedupe

I am trying to fuzzy match two different datasets based on the name column in python.

I am getting an error code that the name is not found in the index. The name variable is a column in both datasets. Can anyone provide me with any suggestions to fix the error?

Here is my code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import fuzzymatcher

al_usa = pd.read_csv('al_all_reference_usa.dta.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
al_sample = pd.read_csv('al_final.dta.csv', skipinitialspace=True)

left_on = ['name', 'state']
right_on = ['name', 'state']

matched_results = fuzzymatcher.fuzzy_left_join(al_usa, 
                                               al_sample, 
                                               left_on, 
                                               right_on, 
                                               left_id_col='id', 
                                               right_id_col='id')
```

Here is my error output:

`````
    raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")
KeyError: "['name'] not in index"````
`````